# How can i disable mouse press event for special widget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I tried to disable it by using attribute `QtCore.Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents`, also I tried to disable my frame, but `ef mousePressEvent(self, event)` is still working

```
import sys
from b import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class main_interface(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.ui.frame.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print('pressed')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = main_interface()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You're overriding the mousePressEvent for the main window subclass, so you're receiving the event for it, not for the frame.

Comment: @musicamante how can i do it for frame?

Comment: Please try to make it clear what you want to achieve. If you make the frame transparent for mouse events, then it will obviously **not** receive mouse events!

Comment: @musicamante My english is bad, but ill try. For example, I have an empty window, from which I removed the default Windows frames, in this window there are only two widgets, I want to make it so that one widget responds to mouse clicks, and the other doesnt

Comment: What do you mean by "responds"? Please try to explain what you *finally* want to achieve, not what you want it to "behave like". Provide a *real* case scenario in which the user can or can't do something, what can happen, and what is the expected result.

Comment: @musicamante i want to receive mouse press event on one widget but ignore it on another, how can this be achieved

Comment: If you want to implement mouse press events for a widget, then subclass that widget and override its mousePressEvent or add an event filter to it. But, in any case, that's not what I asked you. Read my last comment again and answer what is being requested.

Comment: @musicamante For example, a frameless window, that is, there are two widgets, you can drag the window for one widget, and not for the other. How can I define a widget in a subclass that is in my interface file?

Comment: Are you trying to create a custom title bar? Are you on Linux, so you want to disable the default window movement by mouse press on empty spaces?